# Передача аргументов методу

Tags: java

При передаче объекта в качестве параметра методу ссылка должна копироваться. Тогда почему вывод `0 9 9`, а не `9 9 9`? Получается, `s1` и `s2` ссылаются на разные объекты?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer s = 0;
        foo(s, s = 9);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static void foo(Integer s1, Integer s2) {
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Параметры вычисляются слева направо, и поэтому `s1` и `s2` ссылаются на разные объекты. Если вы напишите

```
foo(s = 9, s);
```

То получите `9 9 9`. Так как в этом случае операция `=` выполнится перед вычислением второго параметра. Ваш код равнозначен (за исключением того, что никаких новых переменных нет):

```
Integer s = 0;
// "раскрыл скобки" для foo(s, s = 9);
Integer old_s = s;
s = 9;
foo(old_s, s);
// "раскрыл скобки"
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: т.е. `=` создаёт новый объект, а не изменяет значение старого?

Comment: операция `=` изменяет значение переменной стоящей слева и возвращает значение выражения стоящего справа. поэтому можно сделать вот так `a = b = c = 123`

Comment: это хорошо. Последовательность действий `s=9`: 1) выделяем память под `int` переменную; 2) записывам в нее 9; 3) присваиваем ЭТОТ адрес ссылочной переменной `s` и она теперь указывает на новую область памяти; 4) сборщик мусора освобождает прежний адрес ?

Comment: в 3 пункте автоупаковка

Comment: вы говорите об int или Integer?

Comment: s - ссылочная переменная типа Integer

Comment: это сайт ответов на вопросы. на ваш вопрос вы получили ответ. задайте новый.

Comment: я спросил почему вывод такой, вы написали что если поменять то он будет другим. Это не ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: я вам ответил - так вычисляются параметры при вызове и при вызове функции параметры ссылаются на разные объекты. остальные комментарии уже идут про память и пр.

Comment: ну так в зависимости от ответа на мой вопрос в комментарии ваш ответ   на мой основной вопрос приобретает смысл(для меня). Если `s=9` не изменяет адреса на который указывает `s`, а изменяет только его содержимое, то порядок вычисления аргументов не важен

Comment: когда вы вызываете метод все фактические параметры копируются в стек. формальные параметры берут значения из стека. внутри метода переменной `s` не существует. в методе `main`, переменная `s` меняет свое значение, но оно видно только в этом методе.

Comment: @user232692 по поводу пунктов 1-3: да, так оно и есть. Поэтому в метод передаются значения двух разных ссылок.

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому, что вы - сначала отправляете в первый аргумент, а во втором вы переопределяете переменную на 9.
Одну и туже переменную вы, можете переопределять неограниченное кол.-во раз, только в том случае, если она не final.

```
Integer i = 1;
i = i * 2;
i = i + i;
i-=1;
```

Comment: под "переопределяю" понимается "ссылаюсь на новый объект" или "ссылаюсь на старый измененный объект"?

Comment: Вы изменяете старый - точнее заменяете его на новый с новым значением, иногда полезно, чтобы не создавать новый объект, мы можем сделать все одним и переопределить и сделать столько. сколько нужно будет операций.

Comment: в вашем примере сколько адресов используется?